# Join 3 tables based on Partition by or Self join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have following tables

```
tbl1 (empID, Name, ctNo)

tbl2 (salID, empID, salry)

tbl3 (histryID, salDate, empID, salID)
```

Expect Output `(empID,Name,salary,Salary_Date)`

For Salary date, I only want the last salary_date to be displayed.

(maybe By using Partitiion by or Selfjoin methods.)

Thank You.

Comment: I have tried below query. Its display latest salry_Date ,empId. "  select  emp_Id,salary_Date from (select emp_Id,salary_Date,rank() over(partition by emp_Id 
order by salary_Id desc)as 'ranking' from  tbl_3) testing where ranking<2   "

Comment: My requirement to join " empID(tbl_1),Name(tbl_1),Salary(tbl_2),Salary_Date(tbl_3) "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below query can answer your question

```
Create table #tbl1 (empID int , Name varchar(11), ctNo int)
Create table #tbl2 (salID int, empID int, salry int)
Create table  #tbl3 (histryID int, salDate DATE, empID int, salID int) 


INSERT INTO #tbl1
values(1,'Dinesh',23),(2,'Raj',11)
INSERT INTO #tbl2
values(1,1,1000),(2,1,2000),(3,2,100),(4,2,500)
INSERT INTO #tbl3
values(1,'20020101',1,1),(2,'20020201',1,2),(3,'20020101',2,3),(4,'20020201',2,4)
SELECT M1.* FROM(
SELECT T1.empID,T1.Name,T2.salry,T3.salDate FROM
#tbl1 AS T1
INNER join #tbl2 AS T2
ON T1.empID=T2.empID
INNER join #tbl3 AS T3
ON T1.empID=T3.empID AND T2.salID =T3.salID
) AS M1
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT empID,MAX(salDate) AS SALDATE FROM #tbl3 GROUP BY empID) AS M2
ON M1.SALDATE=M2.salDate AND M1.empID=M2.empID
```

Comment: thank You very much N.Dinesh.Reddy.. Its very usefull. tell me some tips to Improve my SQL knowledge..

Comment: Mark it as answer if this will satisfy your  solution

Comment: Go with strong basics and practice will help you a lot parameswaran

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
select t1.empID, t1.Name, t2.salry as salary, top (t3.salDate) as Salary_Date from tbl1 t1, tbl2 t2, tbl3 t3 on t1.empID=t2.empID and t1.empID=t3.empID
```

Note: Pointing in correct direction. Not tested.

Comment: It will throw `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TOP'.`

Comment: Please you have to check if you have time. Its showing error near " top " and what is tmpID at end of your quey??

Comment: tmp was a typo. Corrected

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'top'.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `row_number` window function:

```
select t1.empid, t1.name, t3.saldate, t2.salary
from tbl1 t1
join(select *, row_number() over(partition by empid order by saldate desc) rn 
     from tbl3)t3 on t1.empid = t3.empid and t3.rn = 1
join tbl2 t2 on t3.empid = t2.empid AND t3.salid = t2.salid
```

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
The multi-part identifier "oa.emp_Id" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
The multi-part identifier "oa.salary_Id" could not be bound.

Comment: Error on " oa " Field.

Comment: What is mean by "  t3.rn=1 "

Comment: @Parameswaran, `row_number() over(partition by empid order by saldate desc) rn ` will number from 1 the rows of employees. You are interested only in latest date so rn should be 1. Just run this and you will see: `select *, row_number() over(partition by empid order by saldate desc) rn 
     from tbl3 order by empid, rn`